# converting a huge amount of street adresses to latitude/longitude coordinates in BATCH?

Tags: php, database, google-maps, coordinates

Please dont mind any mistakes in spelling, because I am writing this on my cellphone ;-)

I have a huge db list which contains thousands of thousand of POI street adresses.. 
And of course its useless to grab each entry (total 58.953 entries), hit it into google maps, copy and paste the coords and save it..

so my question is; how can I solve it and (most likely with php) fetch the lat/lon of each entry...?
is there any possibility to do this with google maps api? How about the error ratio? Or even limited queries :(?

how can I do this?
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend http://tinygeocoder.com.  The API is very simple, and it doesn't have the same kinds of licensing and query limit problems other have had that I have used.

Answer (score 3):

You'd be looking for the [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Note however that there's a limit of 2,500 requests per day unless you pay Google money for a Premier api account (which allows 100,000 per day).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.. does microsoft offers a similar function? just if the limit is exceeded for a day in google :-D

Comment: that being said, a cache is a good idea. Also a proxy server if you plan on making more requests :D